# Insert a zero between 0 to 9 when iterating with python

Tags: python, time-series

I'm writing a code to take a rain time-series and save hourly files for each day in order to feed a hydrological model, so, basically, I need to save each file with the hour of the day with tho digits, like this:

```
rain_20200101_0000.txt
rain_20200101_0100.txt
...
rain_20200101_0900.txt
rain_20200101_1000.txt
..
rain_20200101_2300.txt
```

But python doesn't put a zero before numbers between 0-9, so if I use a `range(24)` to do that it will save the first 10 hours like "rain_20200101_100.txt"

The solution I found was to put an `if` for x<10 and x>=10 inside the `range(24)` and insert a "0" before the hour for the first condition, but I think that is too rude and should be a more eficient way to do that. Could you help me with a simpler solution for this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [string formatting](https://pyformat.info/) to pad with zeros, e.g. `"rain_%04d.txt" %(i)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"123".rjust(4, "0") # 0123
```

see this [treasure](https://pyformat.info/) on formatting

Answer (score 0):

Simple and sweet

```py
>>> '{:04d}'.format(5)
'0005'
```